# Hiding/Showing a div using jQuery based on ASP.NET RadioButtonList selected value (value is opposite for some reason)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am trying to hide/show a div based on my No/Yes ASP.NET RadioButtonList selected value. My code works when I don't have the bootstrap active class on the 'No' item. When it is on the 'No' item for some reason when the user selects 'Yes' value ends up being 'No'.... Here is my code:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatLayout="flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="No" Selected="true" class="btn btn-default active"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes" class="btn btn-default"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

$('#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID%>').click(function () {
    debugger;
    var value = $("#<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %> input:checked").val();
    if (value == "Yes") {
        $('#<%=Panel1.ClientID%>').hide();
    }
    if (value == "No") {
        $('#<%=Panel1.ClientID%>').show();
    }
});
```

**Once code is generated and sent to client:**

```
<span id="GlobalContent_MainContent_RadioButtonList1" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <span class="btn btn-default active">
        <input id="GlobalContent_MainContent_RadioButtonList1_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl00$GlobalContent$MainContent$RadioButtonList1" value="No" checked="checked">
        <label for="GlobalContent_MainContent_RadioButtonList1_0">No</label>
    </span>
    <span class="btn btn-default">
        <input id="GlobalContent_MainContent_RadioButtonList1_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl00$GlobalContent$MainContent$RadioButtonList1" value="Yes" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ctl00$GlobalContent$MainContent$RadioButtonList1$1\',\'\')', 0)"><label for="GlobalContent_MainContent_RadioButtonList1_1">Yes</label>
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Can you show what the above code looks like once it's generated and sent to the client?

Comment: Alright, I added that.. It is very strange that value ends up being no just because of the bootstrap classes.

Comment: Can you also post the generated HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click handler is on the container which could be the source of your problems.

1. Update your event listener to a `change` event instead of a `click` event.
2. Since you're listening to a `change`, you want to update the selector to the actual input where the change will be trigger.

**Updated JS/ASP:**

```
$('#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID%> input').change(function () {
    var $input = $(this),
        $target = $('#<%=Panel1.ClientID%>'),
        value = $input.val();

    if (value === "Yes") {
        $target.hide();
    } else {
        $target.show();
    }
});
```

And here's a running sample based on your generated code:

**Demo:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ar0jy932/2/)

---

**Important Note:**

In almost all cases I would recommend against mixing server side generated code with your JavaScript.  There are many reason why you want to separate the two, but that would fall outside the scope of your question.